# Error Uploading File Using Flash AS3 Scripting

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

Hi guys i have made a website for uploading file but when i upload large file like above 100mb it does not work, sometime it throw io error or somtime it reach to 100% and did not give any response like when its done 100% and when i goto mysql for checking whethere file info uploaded or not but no record.

it works good in localhost but not working properly on server i setup my php ini setting as my localhost php ini. any solution realy appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini change this to something more suiting for you.

> upload_max_filesize = 2m;